# Change width or height of SmartArtNodes

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to change the width or hight of a SmartArtNode?

Following code doesn't work at at all:

```
' mySmartArt is a SmartArt Object
mySmartArt.AllNodes.Item(1).Shapes.Width = 4
```

Strangely enough it works if you change the width of a shape. So I have no clue why Shape Objects of SmartArtNodes can not be resized at all. The only way I know is using the method larger or smaller, but using this method it's not possible to only change the width/high of a shape.

If I use the code above, I'll always get a RunTime Error "Object doesn't support this action (Error 445)", which is strange because via the GUI of Excel I can change the width and height of single Nodes of the SmartArt without a problem. So it doesn't make any sense why it shouldn't be possible to change it via VBA.

Has someone an idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1709060 post of 4 May 13 at 19:23. It seems he is using a layout, I don't know if this could apply to you but it seems interesting enough to take a look at! ;)

Comment: Maybe try mySmartArt.AllNodes.Item(1).Shapes.Item(1).Width?

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers mySmartArt.AllNodes.Item(1).Shapes.Item(1).Width does not work either; it seems it is not possible to change the width or height of a Shape if it's a SmartArtNode; the only stange thing is, that in Excel itself you can change width and height, so it seems strange VBA can't do that

Comment: @R3uK he/she is only changing the height and width of the SmartArt itself, but not of the single Nodes

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim Sma As Shape
Set Sma = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddSmartArt(Application.SmartArtLayouts(2))

With Sma
    .ScaleHeight 1.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromBottomRight
    .ScaleWidth 1.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response. However, your code only changes the size of the whole SmartArt. I also tried to adapt it, so that it only applies to SmartArtNodes, but this didn't work either.